# After power failure I can't compile app anymore

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I sat and coded in Android Studio when the power suddenly went out for a minute. Now whenever I try to build/run my app I get this Gradle error:

> Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've tried Invalidate my Caches&restart, clean and rebuild project serveral times, still get this error.

Comment: You can try to delete the directory `.gradle` in your home directory

Comment: And... buy an UPS or develop on a laptop (the battery will act as an UPS).

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @BobMalooga or work in a data center :D

Comment: You can run a little power plant next to your computer too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I copy my comment here because it's working:*

You can try to delete the directory `.gradle` in your home directory.

`rm -rf ~/.gradle/` for linux or OSX system.
`RD /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\"` for Windows.

Comment: NOTE! Delete   .gradle    folder in your Project Directory no the one in your Home Directory.

Comment: @DLastCodeBender why?